# Pandas KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem' when trying to use .loc property

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when I'm trying to call the following code i get the error **KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'**.

`Base.loc[ 'CDD1' in Base['col'], 'test'] = "abc"`

When i change the code as shown below there are no errors, but unfortunetly, that's not the case, i need to slice the data frame to find all rows where the column 'col' **contains** the string 'CDD1'.

`Base.loc[ Base['col'] == 'CDD1', 'test'] = "abc"`

Comment: What is the data type of `Base['col']`? Can you provide an example value?

Comment: `Base.loc[ Base['col'].str.contains('CDD1'), 'test'] = "abc"`

Comment: Looks like the `.str.contains` method is working. Thank you!